# Unity3d Resources.LoadAll<Sprite> empty array

Tags: c#, unity

In my resources folder structure I have myself a file, now in the unity editor this file is a `Texture Type Sprite (2D and UI)`, now when I attempt to run this code in one of my scripts

`var icons = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>("Images/BuffIcons");`

My icons variable is empty, now if I change the line above to

`var icons = Resources.LoadAll("Images/BuffIcons");`

It comes back with an array which has a `Texture2D` and then multiple `Sprite` objects. Now why can't I cast the objects to a `Sprite`?

Also just for your information the `Sprite (2D and UI)` is a `Multiple` sprite so this sprite in total has like 42 different sprites. It seems to me the sprite which holds all the other sprites is classed as a `Texture2D` and then all the sprites inside of the `Texture2D` are Sprites. How can I just tell the Resources.LoadAll to load the sprites?

Basically the same problem as this user http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/900990/assetdatabaseloadallassetsatpath-not-loading-asset.html however the answers provided don't work for me either :(

Answer (score 3):

So this is a really silly answer however I'm not going to delete this question because around the web I have seen this question in a view places and all the answer's didn't work for me so. Here is my fix :D

Basically I have a `Sprite (2D and UI)` file in Assets/Resources/Images/BuffIcons, in my code I have this line

```
BuffIconSprites = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>("Images/BuffIcons");
```

Basically all I had to do was simply close Unity and re-open it, it seems if you create the sprite asset which contains multiple sprites you need to close and reopen Unity, I think this is something to do with the solution file which is constantly updated when stuff changing in your Unity file.

P.S. as you can see the line of code I provided hasn't changed. So I'm 100% sure this problem is something to do with the Unity solution

Answer (score 1):

Going to Unity's menu system, selecting `Assets` and then `Reimport All` will do the trick.

This better than re-opening unity, since that does not always reimport your assets fully when the project is in a funny state. This will ensure all such issues are corrected. (Just had this issue, and opening / closing did not help - `Resources.LoadAll()` failed to load *anything* until `Reimport All` was used. Checked textures after first close/reopen and they were in an unreadable state in `Project` tab).